# No. of parabolas possible for the given equation.

Tags: quadratics

Given, $f(x)=-x^2+qx+r$.   $(q,r) \epsilon R$.  $q,r$ are variables. A quadratic equation $f(x)=0$ has a maximum value $m$ ($m$ is a constant) and a root $x=a$. Does $f(x)$ correspond to a unique parabola? Why?

Comment: The short answer is: It depends on $m$. Details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given, $f(x)=-x^2+qx+r$.   $(q,r) \epsilon R$.  A quadratic equation
>   $f(x)=0$ has a maximum value $m$

The function might have a maximum.
$$
f(x) = -(x^2 - qx - r) =
-\left( (x-q/2)^2 -(q^2/4) -r \right)
$$
The quadratic term is minimal and with the minus sign maximal, if $x=q/2$.
So $f$ has a maximum there. The value is 
$$
m = (q^2/4) + r \quad (*)
$$

> and a root $x=a$.

$$
0 = f(x) = -\left( (x-q/2)^2 -(q^2/4) -r \right) \iff \\
x = \frac{q \pm \sqrt{q^2+4r}}{2} = \frac{q \pm \sqrt{4m}}{2} \quad (**)
$$
The number and kind of roots are determined by the term $\Delta = q^2+4r$. If $\Delta = 0$, there is only one root $x=q/2$. If $\Delta > 0$ there are two real roots, if $\Delta <0$ there are no real valued roots (but two complex ones).

> Does $f(x)$ correspond to a unique parabola? Why?

If that root $x=a$ is the only root, then the above gives that it is $a=q/2$ and that $q=2a$ from $0 =\Delta = q^2+4r$ we know that $r = -a^2$. Thus both coefficients $q, r$ are uniquely determined as the parabola is too.

If there is a second root or if we do not know the number of roots, and this seems to be the case for this task, then we need more information.
As additional information we got the value $m$ of the maximum of $f$, thus $m = f(x^*)$, for some unknown argument $x^*$.

We have two equations, for the maximum we have $(*)$ and for the root we have $(**)$. This leads to:

$$
q = 2a \mp \sqrt{4m} \quad (\#) \\
r = m - (q^2 / 4)
$$

If $m = 0$ then we have only one root, and the parabola is uniquely determined.

If $m > 0$, then we have two roots and we do not know which of the two possible signs for the square root in $(\#)$ applies, if the maximum is to the right ($a < x^*$) or to the left of $a$ ($x^* < a$).

So in this case we limit it down to two possible parabolas, with two different coefficients $q, r$, but we can not decide which of the two we are dealing with.

Here are graphs for $a = 2$ and $m = 0$ and $m = 1$:

[image: case m = 0] 
[image: case m > 0]

Answer (score 1):

What is given? What is required?

**If $q,r$ are given**, then the roots and extreme value are fixed automatically as

$   \dfrac{q \pm \sqrt{q^2+4r}}{2},  (r + q^2/4 ) $ respectively, obtained by standard method of finding roots and extreme values by differentiation.

The two  constants $ q,r$ determine only one unique $ y = f(x) = -x^2 + q x + r  $ parabola graph.

Do not assign new symbols to  dependent quantities $ a, m$ as if they are new or independent!

However,

**If $ a, m $  are given**

Take  the parabola equation in the form $ A y = -(x-a)(x-b) $

Differentiating,  $ x_{max}= (a+b)/2 $

Maximum value of parabola is found as

$$ y_m = m = (b-a)^2/(4 A) $$

Find $b$ from above and plug into parabola equation to get one parabola for *each value of $A$ chosen*.

$$ A y = A f(x) = - (x-a)(x-a-2 \sqrt{m A} ) $$

So the parabolas are not unique like in the first case, they *are infinitely many*, as seen in the graph where I chose four values for the arbitrary constant $A$.

Treat the problems *separately* to avoid confusion.

In the example given  $ m =1000, a= 1 , (0.05 < A < 0.2) $

EDIT 1:

We can drive home that  $A$ is an arbitrary maximum curvature at all top points of same height $m$ for a particular boundary condition chosen.  we can formulate a simple differential equation approach as well:

$$ y{''} = -1/A , y ' = -x/A + \tan \alpha , y = - x^2/ (2 A) + x \tan \alpha $$

( arbitrary constant set to $0$ for $x=0,y=0)$.

The $\alpha$ is the variable angle to ground fired by an imaginary gun for the projectile to reach same height $m$. It has two roots

$$ x=0, x = 2 A \tan \alpha ;$$

with maximum height for all $\alpha$

$$ y = y_{max}  = m = A \tan {^2}\alpha /2 $$

for all $\alpha$ at $ x= A \tan \alpha.$  The variable $\alpha$ is given by:

$$ \tan \alpha = \sqrt{2 m/A} $$

[image: No of Parabolas possible for given a,m]

[We can compare it to a dynamic  projectile problem where the vertical component of velocity (proportional to maximum height reached) of a gun shot fired with  velocity in various directions].

Comment: q,r ain't given.

Comment: If (q,r) are given then take the first option. If (a,m) are given then take second option.They are distinctly different cases.

Comment: $q,r$ are variables (not given) but $a,m$ are constants (given). So, it's two parabolas, right?

Comment: In the second option there are    **infinitely many**  solution parabolas depending on the value of A chosen as given in my answer.      In the first option I have considered $q,r$ as constants.

Comment: @Narasimham In the OP, $A=1$.

Comment: Nowhere in his posting or thereafter in his comments has he stated it as such. Please note, A is curvature of the parabola when it touches a line y= m =constantt. I shall post an integration scheme with this constant maximum through a single fixed point (x=a=0),(x=a=0),  for all the parabola set.

Answer (score 0):

It need not be a unique parabola. Think geometrically of two possibilities consider a concave down parabola passing through the point $(a,0)$ with maximum value $m$. In one case the left branch passes through $(a,0)$ and in the other case the right branch passes through $(a,0)$. Hence not unique.

Comment: Got you. That means for one root $x=a$, of $f(x)$ we'll get two other roots, one for each of the case,  right?

Comment: @AnubhabDas yes. Since one root is $x=a$, the other root will be $x=q-a$. So the parabola you have will be $y=-(x-a)(x+a-q)$. Now you can have two possibilities $q>2a$ or $q<2a$. In one case maximum occurs at $x=a+q/2$ and in the other it occurs at $a-q/2$.

Comment: Where from are you getting $q>2a$ or $q<2a$ ?